# selector disable botton

Tags: android

I have this selector for one of my button's background

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false"
          android:drawable="@drawable/bg_botton_disable"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:state_enabled="true"  
          android:drawable="@drawable/bg_botton_pressed"/> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_enabled="true" 
          android:drawable="@drawable/bg_botton" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

```java
(Button) bt = (Button) findviewById(R.id.MyBotton);
bt.setEnabled(false);
```

The code disables the functionality of my button. I mean when I press the button it doesn't launch its own `onClick()` method. That's fine, but the problem is that it doesn't change the background of the button to `bg_botton_disable` drawable.

Does anyone has any suggestion how to fix it?

Comment: One concern here: `android:state_pressed` for the first item - isn't it mandatory? Do you have another layout, which is named "bg_botton_disable"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reorder your selector items

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="true" 
          android:drawable="@drawable/bg_botton" /> <!-- default -->
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/bg_botton_pressed"/> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_enabled="false"
          android:drawable="@drawable/bg_botton_disable"/>
</selector>
```